# Iterate through an array in an array of dictionaries swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am currently in a bit of a bind.

```
struct sectionWithDatesAsName {
    var sectionName : String
    var sectionObjects : [SoloTransactionModel]!
    
    init(uniqueSectionName: String?, sectionObject: [SoloTransactionModel]?) {
        sectionName = uniqueSectionName ?? "nil"
        if let section = sectionObject {
            sectionObjects = section.reversed()
        }
        
    }
}
```

I currently have an array of `sectionWithDatesAsName`. And I can work with it, display in the tableView among other things.

The bind comes up when I want to check some information in the `sectionObject` before displaying it on the tableView.

I want to check the **type** of the `sectionObject` which is saved in the object itself.

How do I check the information in the `sectionObject` without slowing down the app? Or have a horrible time complexity calculated?

*(Note: I can't change the format of the struct has this has already been used by a whole lot of other processes)*

Comment: What do you mean "I want to check some data in the sectionObject before saving displaying it on the tableView"? Do you want to filter the array of sectionObjects and only show some of them by type? And you don't want to do the work to filter the array of sectionObjects every time you access it?

Comment: Exactly, I would like to filter by type before I access it.

Comment: Have you tried using [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function in your sectionWithDatesAsName with the signature `filteredSections(type: sectionType) -> sectionWithDatesAsName`

(If you don't have the ability to edit the definition of sectionWithDatesAsName you can create an extension that adds the above function)

If the sectionWithDatesAsName is defined elsewhere, define this function in an extension.

When you call it, build a new `sectionWithDatesAsName` object by filtering the arrays to match the specified type.

Use the resulting filtered sectionWithDatesAsName object as the data model for your table view. It will be built once and used for the lifetime of the tableView, so you will pay an `O(n)` time cost to filter it once when you create it.